# query for update mean values from regular data is not working well

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to insert mean monthly values from one table to other table as mean values but it's not working well

```
`UPDATE avg_month_val 
set 
    year          =   YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')), 
    month         =   MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')), 
    evep          =   ROUND(AVG(`evep`), 2), 
    sunshine_hrs  =   ROUND(AVG(`sunshine_hrs`) ,2), 
    rainfall      =   ROUND(SUM(`rainfall`), 2), 
    max_temp      =   ROUND(AVG(`max_temp`), 2), 
    min_temp      =   ROUND(AVG(`min_temp`), 2) 

FROM 
    reg_data3 

GROUP BY 
    MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')), 
    MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')) `
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: What do you mean by "mean monthly values"? Do you mean the 15th day? I would kindly suggest to reform your question by removing all the unnecessary parts of it (I guess sunshine_hrs and max_temp) are not important for the question...

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan according to SQlyog Enterprise give error "check the maqnual that right syntax; check thwe manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near "FROM reg_data3 GROUP BY MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('date', '%Y-%m-%d'),

Comment: @PantelisNatsiavas Avearage values of month inser to avg_month_val1 table

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan please help me sir i'm new comer

Comment: @user3032532, `Please help me` phrase never works well on SO. Just explain things clearly on your question and eventually you will be getting answers.

Comment: if i assume correctly, you should use insert with inner select query

Comment: Isolate the error. Try to remove the unnecessary expressions. I would use **fixed** values for all the fields and check the query (eg numbers like 1). If the query was fine, I would add the expressions one by one and find out which one is causing the problem. In a statement like this, where you have 10 or more conversions, of course you would have a syntactic error. Right?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran iwant to select values from regular table and insert to average table with year,month,values of columns i write this query but it is error how i overcome in my trouble

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan yes i can insert but problem is if i use insert  all are pass to average table also present month values but end of this month some values are enter to regular table usung insert query i unable to do it fruiend

Answer (score 0):

Don't know wether this is a copy-error while posting but

```
GROUP BY 
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')), 
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

doesn't make sense and should show an error. You should do

```
GROUP BY 
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')), 
YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Also `update` just changes values in existing rows and for most cases requires a `where`-clause to sepcify which rows to change. for inserting values you'd want

```
INSERT INTO avg_month_val (`year`,`month`,`evep`,`sunshine_hrs`,`rainfall`,`max_temp`,`min_temp`)
select 
YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')), 
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')), 
ROUND(AVG(`evep`), 2), 
ROUND(AVG(`sunshine_hrs`) ,2), 
ROUND(SUM(`rainfall`), 2), 
ROUND(AVG(`max_temp`), 2), 
ROUND(AVG(`min_temp`), 2) 
FROM 
reg_data3 
GROUP BY 
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')), 
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```